# Why does a heterogeneous result of Promise.all cause a TS error?

Tags: typescript

The following code causes a compilation error even though it seems correct:

```
type Name = { name: string };
type NamePlus = { name: string, hair: string };

type ReturnType = { foo: Name, bar: NamePlus };

export async function test(): Promise<ReturnType> {
  const myName: Name = { name: 'Tom' };
  const myNamePlus: NamePlus = { name: 'Larry', hair: 'black' };

  const result = await Promise.all([myName, myNamePlus]);

  return {
    foo: result[0],
    bar: result[1],
  };
}
```

The TS error is:

```
Type '{ foo: Name; bar: Name; }' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType'.
   Types of property 'bar' are incompatible.
     Type 'Name' is not assignable to type 'NamePlus'.
       Property 'hair' is missing in type 'Name'.
```

It seems something is awry with structural subtyping, but I'm not clear on exactly what is causing this error. I'd love an explanation.

Comment: This isn't an error in the TypeScript Playground. http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ - are you maybe using an older version?

Comment: We're using Webpack + ts-loader, and the error is being emitted through there. I'm working to unfurl why. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

This error only happens in Typescript 2.4. The latest version of Typescript resolves the problem.